# How to return a value from an object method?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an object with a few functions. I am not able to retrieve the returned value when I access the utils.run function, Please help.

```
 var utils = {
    "init" : function(){
             console.log("init");
    },

     "run" : function(value1){
             return "hello"+value1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code, and it works. How are you trying to use `utils.run`?

Comment: Don't confuse JSON with JavaScript. What you have is a **JavaScript object**, not JSON. [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I think you were just trying to do utils.run but as you need to call a function in JavaScript you need to use the function invocation operator i.e. () so you would call the function in the JavaScript object as utils.run(' world');

Comment: @FelixKling But ofcourse [there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ...

Comment: @Teemu: From the post: *"So, maybe I fibbed a little. While Object literals are not “JSON Objects,” there really is [a JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_native_JSON), but it’s something else entirely."*

Comment: Thanks . Its running now. I gave the wrong command to run utils.run()

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me:

```js
 var utils = {
   "init": function() {
     console.log("init");
   },

   "run": function(value1) {
     return "hello" + value1;
   }
 };

 console.log(utils.run(' there!'));
```

Just a side note: This is a regular JavaScript object, not a JSON. JSONs do not have executable functions because they are a notation to send data over the wire (as a string). It just looks like a JS object ... and that's is also why it's called **J**ava**S**cript**O**bject**N**otation ;-)

Comment: If there is no problem then the question should be closed as *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."* instead.

Comment: Thanks . Its running now.  I gave the wrong command to run utils.run.